# Как передать структуру через сигналы и слоты

Tags: c++, qt

Как передать структуру через сигналы --- слоты?
Гуглил ответы есть но я понять не смог. Если можно то по рабоче-крестьянски.

Вот моя структура:

```
struct massifVoltageAndIndex{
unsigned short int Voltage;
unsigned short int index;
unsigned short int temperature;
unsigned short int fault;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(massifVoltageAndIndex)
```

Добавил в .cpp

```
static int psbk_id = qRegisterMetaType<massifVoltageAndIndex>();
```

Добавил в класс 
    private:
    massifVoltageAndIndex Balanser[247];

Добавил сигнал

```
void signalInfoAuto(const massifVoltageAndIndex & Balanser);
```

передаю сигнал:
    emit signalInfoAuto(massifVoltageAndIndex & Balanser());

получил ошибку 
 error: expected primary-expression before ‘&’ token
  emit signalInfoAuto(massifVoltageAndIndex & Balanser());

Comment: `emit SomeSignal(some_struct);`?

Comment: посмотрите - вдруг поможет http://cppstudio.com/post/11167/    .

А передать ссылку или указатель на структуру как обычно ,
можете и объект сам по идее ... всё это  - аргументами функции

Answer (score 4):

Для того, чтобы передать класс (или структуру) через сигнал-слот, нужно включить его в систему MOC.
Это можно сделать следующим образом:

```
class communicationPlane{
public:
    QDateTime makeDate;
    QDateTime changeDate;
    QString fileName;
    QByteArray data;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(communicationPlane)
```

Макрос **Q_DECLARE_METATYPE** определяет метакласс для нашего класса.

После этого в cpp-файле пишете

```
static int psbk_id = qRegisterMetaType<communicationPlane>();
```

Что обеспечит регистрацию класса в системе MOC, и, соответственно, позволит передавать его через сигналы обычным способом:

```
communicationPlan p;
emit cp_signal(p);
```

Есть ли какая-то польза от значения, возвращаемого *qRegisterMetaType*, я, честно говоря, не понял.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102105/discussion-on-answer-by---------).

Answer (score 1):

Минимальный пример, в котором посредством сигнально-слотовой связи передается структура. Никаких сложностей, все как со встроенными типами.

Тут стоит обратить внимание на то, что структура создается в локальной области памяти, но передается по константной ссылке. Т.к. и источник и приемник живут в одном потоке, это вполне допускается (вызов сигнала == вызов функции). Но даже если слот будет находиться в другом потоке, работоспособность должна сохраниться, т.к. `moc` - система создаст копию объекта.

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

struct S {unsigned a, b;};

class A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void go() {emit signal(S({42, 1}));}
signals:
    void signal(const S &);
};

class B : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void slot(const S &s) {qDebug() << s.a << s.b;}
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;

    QObject::connect(&a, &A::signal, &b, &B::slot);
    a.go();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: А если структура будет внутри класса в private? То как тогда будет выглядеть код?

Comment: @zhilenkov, так сигнал посылается из метода класса, внутри метода доступ к приватным членам ни чем не ограничен. Или вы про случай, когда структура определена внутри класса, как у вас в вопросе? Тут явная ошибка проектирования. Ведь если слот принимает данные, значит, он должен все знать об их структуре, иначе, зачем ему эти данные?

Answer (score -2):

самое простое в качестве примера  ...

```
    class MyActions : public QObject
        {
          Q_OBJECT

        public:
          MyActions ... {};
          ...
        private slots:
          void clicked();
        };



        void MyActions::clicked()
        {
          info("Button is clicked");
        }


        int main()
        {
        ...
              MyActions *actions = new MyActions(.....);
              // create a widget
              QPushButton *b = new QPushButton("Click here", w);

             // connect the button to a slot

              QObject::connect(b, SIGNAL(clicked()), actions, SLOT(clicked()));

            return 0;
        }
```

при передаче структуры куда либо вы должны учитывать тот факт , что вы передадите только набор параметров ( переменных ) определенных данной структурой или чем либо другим - контейнером , массивом или любым другим объектом вашего класса .
Вы должны учитывать тот факт, что для работы со значениями , если вы не собираетесь их изменять вы можете использовать ссылку на структуру .
Если вы хотите как то обработать данные структуры и изменить их потом  - вам нужно передать указатель на структуру .
Так же учтите , что структура ваша , пусть не сейчас , как в примере , но в дальнейшем , может весить слишком много , и если вы собираетесь производить достаточно большое количество операций с вашей структурой  - это сильно повлияет на производительность по времени ...
В приведенном выше примере в конструкторе класса MyAction вы можете создавать всё что захотите , как структуру , так и любой нужный вам объект .
Этот объект может как принадлежать классу и иметь публичные и приватные поля класса , так и не принадлежать классу . И делайте потом всё что вам необходимо ... Ссылка на ещё один пример есть в комментариях . Продублирую на всякий случай https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025182/how-to-pass-qobject-as-argument-from-signal-to-slot-in-qt-connect

Comment: Где здесь передача структуры?

Comment: http://blog.kislenko.net/show.php?id=1930
http://blog.kislenko.net/show.php?id=1708

здесь по тегу Qt много примеров   
http://blog.kislenko.net/tag.php?id=195

Comment: @maestro  - аргументами функции можно передать ...

Comment: Ни в вашем коде, ни в коде, приведённом по ссылкам, нет передачи структур. Аргументами функции можно передать не любые параметры, а только те, которые включены в метаобъектный компилятор, как справедливо отметил Юрий Козлов. Здесь же не содержится ответа на вопрос.

Comment: а ссылку или указатель на структуру тоже нельзя передать ?

Comment: Как я понял нет. В этом вся и сложность.

Comment: я конечно может туплю - но в чем проблема передачи в Qt  параметров из функции в функцию по указателю ? это ничем не отличается от плюсов . Нет креатора установленного , но здесь в принципе тоже самое :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025182/how-to-pass-qobject-as-argument-from-signal-to-slot-in-qt-connect